# Pass encrypted value from xml file to ms build command

Tags: jenkins, ansible-playbook, xml

I have a xml file with passwords in it. I have to pass these passwords from a xml file to password property in MSBUILD command.
Can anyone guide me

Xml:

```
<?xml versio------>
<configuration>
<password>newpassword</password>
</configuration>
```

My msbuild command is:

```
Msbuild "projectpath" /p:deployonbuild=true /p:username='user's /p:password=' '
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `xml` module in https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/xml_module.html and there is an example to retrieve a xml value from an XML file

```
# Consider the following XML file:
#
# <business type="bar">
#   <name>Tasty Beverage Co.</name>
#     <beers>
#       <beer>Rochefort 10</beer>
#       <beer>St. Bernardus Abbot 12</beer>
#       <beer>Schlitz</beer>
#    </beers>
#   <rating subjective="true">10</rating>
#   <website>
#     <mobilefriendly/>
#     <address>http://tastybeverageco.com</address>
#   </website>
# </business>

# Retrieve and display the number of nodes
- name: Get count of 'beers' nodes
  community.general.xml:
    path: /foo/bar.xml
    xpath: /business/beers/beer
    count: yes
  register: hits

- ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: hits.count

# ...

# How to read an attribute value and access it in Ansible
- name: Read an element's attribute values
  xml:
    path: /foo/bar.xml
    xpath: /business/website/validxhtml
    content: attribute
  register: xmlresp

- name: Show an attribute value
  debug:
    var: xmlresp.matches[0].validxhtml.validatedon
```

You can adopt that for your needs. In Ansible 2.9 use `xml` instead of `community.general.xml` and be aware of installing the necessary libs (lxml)